# Unix: zip folder ignoring folder structure and excluding a subdirectory

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, zip

I want to create a zip ignoring the folder structure, and excluding the content of a  specific subfolder.

I have tried:

```
zip -rj /path/to/target.zip /path/to/source -x "/path/to/source/subfolder/*"
```

It doesnt't work, zip returns the message:

zip error: Nothing to do! (/path/to/target.zip)

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt of `man 1 zip`

> [...]
> an input pattern such as
>
> ```
>        /foo/bar/*
> ```
>
> normally would match both paths, the * matching dir/file1.c and file2.c.  Note that in the first case a directory boundary (/) was crossed in the match. With -ws no directory bounds will be included in the match, making wildcards local to a specific directory level.  So, with -ws enabled, only the second path would be matched.
>
> When using -ws, use ** to match across directory boundaries as * does normally.

This is also true when using `-x`

So for your purpose double the `*` at the exclusion pattern, if it's a directory:

```
zip -rj /path/to/target.zip /path/to/source -x "/path/to/source/subfolder/**"
```

Comment: Did this solve your question?